# Best way to include inside a view other view

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a site written with mvc Codeigniter. I want that inside a view in a specific position call another view because for example the menu is repeated in many pages and is the same for all.

In my controller I have write this:

```
public function home()
    {
      $data['menu_function'] = $this->load->view('backend/include/menu_function_view');
      $data['menu'] = $this->load->view('backend/include/menu_view');
      $this->load->view('backend/include/header_view_logged');
      $this->load->view('backend/home_view',$data);
      $this->load->view('backend/include/footer_view');
    }
```

and into my home_view

```
<?php 
echo($menu_function);
?>
<div id="page">
    <?php 
    echo($menu);
    ?>
     <div id="content">
....
```

The problem is that the content inside $menu is out form page. I have seen that in firebug ithe html is like this:

```
<div id="menu">
...
</div>
   <div id="page">
    ...
   </div>
```

instead of:

```
<div id="page">
     <div id="menu">
      ...
     </div>
   </div>
```

How can I solve It?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if this the best approach but usually I use to create template file that load view in it. Here the basic idea:

in folder view I create file template.php that contains:

```
$this->load->view('includes/header');
$this->load->view( $main_content );
$this->load->view('includes/footer');
```

I then create folder view/include which contains:

file `header.php and footer.php`

In controller I call:

```
$data['main_content'] = 'user/dashboard';
$this->load->view('template', $data);
```

EDIT: The menu problem

How about passing the data like $menu_config to your header or view template.

header.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>$title</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php 
    if($menu_position == 'top1') { 
        $this->load->view($menu);
    }
?>
```

On Controller:

```
$data['main_content'] = 'user/dashboard';
$data['menu'] = 'top_menu';
$data['menu_position'] = 'top1';
$this->load->view('template', $data);
```

Comment: and is how I have done with header and footer but if a menu is in a specific part I want to insert it in a specific div

Comment: How about my edited answer?

Comment: It's an idea and works because with $this->load->view($menu); I can make a funxtion like "include" and works fine